# replacing a small brake line in the rear of a 2006 Kia Spectra,

Tags: brakes, kia, bleeding, spectra

the small brake line burst on the rear of our 2006 Kia Spectra , I just replaced the line, once it is together ,do I need to bleed the other side.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: There will be a specific order, usually farthest first, nearest last, but do check.

Comment: You need to bleed at all four corners, starting from the corner furthest away hydraulically.

Comment: if one  brake line have burst you need to take a look on the other brake lines and look for cracks and wear and change the bad ones if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Once it's together, you need to bleed the entire system, as air could have entered and affect the braking ability of the vehicle. Since it's a 2006, if you're like most people, the brake fluid has never been changed in it anyway. Doing a complete flush and bleeding at all four is not going to hurt anything. Get yourself a quart of DOT4 and have at it.